# Isotope Overlapping Images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

It seems like it only happens in Chrome and Safari.. not Firefox.  I'm using it with the foundation responsive framework so I'm not sure what to do about setting the height.  It also seems there isnt enough spacing between the images in Chrome/Safari..

How do I fix this?

Edit: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TLjay/

The problem with it is that it doesn't seem to be displaying the problem I'm having.. so I'm not sure what to do about that.. I've tried disabling everything but isotope.. all jquery/css and It still shrinks the images in Chrome/Safari but its fine in firefox.

Also, If I hit the "All" under filter it stretches the page to how its suppose to look so that could be helpful in figuring this out

I got it to work with imagesLoaded, so its giving enough space but the space on the left and right of the images is still not where its suppose to be.. my script is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $container = $('.isosort')
    // initialize Isotope
        $container.isotope({
            // options...
            resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
            layoutMode : 'fitRows',
            animationEngine : 'best-available',

            // set columnWidth to a percentage of container width
            masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
        });

        // update columnWidth on window resize
        $(window).smartresize(function(){
            $container.isotope({
            // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
            masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
            });
        });
        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){

                $container.isotope({
            // options...
                });
        });

        $('#filters a').click(function(){
            var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Add code to your question please.

Comment: @Abbas updated question with a fiddle

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update** (*original answer was wrong because the browser used cached images..*)

The issue seems to be that the images are not loaded and the calculations fail.

If you wrap the isotop code in `$(window).load(function(){ ..... });` it seems to work as expected..

See http://jsfiddle.net/TLjay/2/

---

<strike>Not sure why it happens, but a simple workaround is (*since it gets fixed once you resize the window*) to manually call a `resize`.</strike>

so just adding `$(window).resize();` at the end of your code fixes it..

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/TLjay/1/

Comment: It would be better to use the included [imagesLoaded plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#images).

Comment: @thirtydot updated main post with imagesLoaded, but the gutters are still thin how do I fix that part?

Comment: This doesn't always work, even in 2014. For example, if you're in a Foundation 5 block grid, it'll still happen on a back button press. Explicitly adding the isInitLayout: true fixes the issue. That's a default, but adding it explicitly seems to work around an invisible source order problem.

Answer (score 7):

imagesLoaded works by checking the images currently in the containing element. So in your case, it's not actually do anything in $(window).load() since there are no items in that element. Instead, I would recommend triggering imagesLoaded again, after items have been inserted with the $.ajax.success

```
success: function(data){
    // Update isotope container with new data. 
    $container.isotope('remove', $container.data('isotope').$allAtoms )
    $container.isotope('insert', $(data) )
      // trigger isotope again after images have been loaded
      .imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.isotope('reLayout');
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Good idea to call relayout again after images have loaded. This worked for me!

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem, so I'd like to try your solution, but I'm not sure where to put the code. After a code that uses ImagesLoaded?

Comment: add this code in your jquery ajax call, like this:     $.ajax({

                cache: false, url: getQuery,
                success: function (data) {
               
            
                    $container.append(divs).isotope('appended', divs, function () {

                        $container.isotope('reLayout');
                    });
                    if (stButtons) { stButtons.locateElements(); }

                }
            });

Answer (score 1):

In case you have the dimensions of the images available you could do a workaround with SVG placeholders.

For example: Use a figure element and position the img with "position: absolute" on top of the svg.

This way isotope renders the gridelement with the SVG that occupies the space and puts the img on top it.

```
<figure>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  width="[inputKnownImageWidth]"
  height="[inputKnownImageHeight]"
></svg>
<img src="" alt="">
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you preload all imagess before you call isotope method, here is real world demo for this:  http://gbin1.com/gb/demoviewer/360/06242ba0-40a1-45fd-946f-cc89e0df64c9/index.html.htm , you preload images with jquery.imagesloaded.min.js plugin, then call isotope , content won't get overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

Here are solutions for Isotope Overlapping. also code for ISOTOPE FILTER with Search & Load more.

The code is also working in WEBFLOW

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.js"></script>
<script>

$(window).on('load', function(){
setTimeout(function(){ 
        //Isotope Code place here 
     
 // external js: isotope.pkgd.js

  // store filter for each group
  var buttonFilters = {};
  var buttonFilter;
  // quick search regex
  var qsRegex;

  // init Isotope
 
  var $grid = $('.mentor-lisitng').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.mentor-col',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    filter: function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
      var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
      return searchResult && buttonResult;
    },

  });
 

  // use value of search field to filter
  var $quicksearch = $('.quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
    qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
    $grid.isotope();
  }) );
  // use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('.iso-search button').on( 'click',function() {

    qsRegex = new RegExp( document.getElementById('quicksearch').value, 'gi' );
  $grid.isotope();
});

// Search when someone pushes enter in the text field
$("#quicksearch").click(function(e){ 
     if(e.key === 16 || e.key === 13 || e.key === 'Enter') {
qsRegex = new RegExp( document.getElementById('quicksearch').value, 'gi' );
  $grid.isotope();
     }
});



  $('.filter-dropdown').on( 'click', '.w-dyn-item', function() {
    //   loadMore(initShow);
    //   $('#load-more').show();
    var $this = $(this);
    // get group key
    var $buttonGroup = $this.parents('.w-dyn-items');
    var filterGroup = $buttonGroup.attr('data-filter-group');
    // set filter for group
    buttonFilters[ filterGroup ] = $this.attr('data-filter');
    // combine filters
    buttonFilter = concatValues( buttonFilters );
    // Isotope arrange
    $grid.isotope();
    $('.filter-dropdown .w-dyn-items > .w-dyn-item:first-child').each(function(){
      if($('.filter-dropdown .w-dyn-items > .w-dyn-item:first-child').hasClass('is-checked') && $('.ui-group:nth-child(2) .button-group > button:first-child').hasClass('is-checked') && $('.ui-group:nth-child(3) .button-group > button:first-child').hasClass('is-checked') && $('.filter-dropdown .w-dyn-items > .w-dyn-item:first-child').hasClass('is-checked')){
        loadMore(initShow);
        $('#load-more').show();
      }else{
        $('#load-more').hide();
      }
    });
    loadMore(initShow);
  });

  

  // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.filter-dropdown .w-dyn-items').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', '.w-dyn-item', function() {

      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');

      if ($(".filter-dropdown .w-dyn-items").length > 0) {
        $(".mentor-col").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#load-more").hide();
        //       $(".noResult").show();
      }


    });

  });

  // flatten object by concatting values
  function concatValues( obj ) {
    var value = '';
    for ( var prop in obj ) {
      value += obj[ prop ];
    }
    return value;
  }

  // debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
  function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
    var timeout;
    threshold = threshold || 100;
    return function debounced() {
      clearTimeout( timeout );
      var args = arguments;
      var _this = this;
      function delayed() {
        fn.apply( _this, args );
      }
      timeout = setTimeout( delayed, threshold );
    };
  }


//   $('.video-library .ui-group h3, .case-studies-filters .ui-group h3').on('click', function() {
//     $(this).parent().toggleClass('filter-open');
//   });

  
 



  
  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.mentor-lisitng').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.mentor-col',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  });



  //****************************
  // Isotope Load more button
  //****************************
  
  var initShow = 8; //number of images loaded on init & onclick load more button
  var counter = initShow; //counter for load more button
  var iso = $container.data('isotope'); // get Isotope instance

  loadMore(initShow); //execute function onload

  //append load more button
  $container.after('<div class="fullwidth load-btn"><button id="load-more" class="link-19">See more</button></div>');
  function loadMore(toShow) {
    $container.find(".hidden").removeClass("hidden");

    var hiddenElems = iso.filteredItems.slice(toShow, iso.filteredItems.length).map(function(item) {
      return item.element;
    });
    var count_items = $(hiddenElems).length;
    $(hiddenElems).addClass('hidden');
    $container.isotope('layout');

    //when no more to load, hide show more button
    if (count_items > 0) {
      $("#load-more").show();
    } 
    else {
      $("#load-more").hide();
    };
    
  }



  //when load more button clicked
  $("#load-more").click(function() {
    if ($('.filter-dropdown .w-dyn-items').data('clicked')) {
      //when filter button clicked, set initial value for counter
      counter = initShow;
      $('.filter-dropdown .w-dyn-items').data('clicked', false);
    } else {
      counter = counter;
    };
 
    counter = counter + initShow;

    loadMore(counter);
  });

  $(".filter-dropdown .w-dyn-items").click(function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
    loadMore(initShow);
  });
  // Show message if there were no results
  $container.on( 'layoutComplete', function( event, laidOutItems ) {
    if ( laidOutItems.length == 0 ) {
      $(".no-results").show();
    } else if ( $(".no-results").length ) {
      $(".no-results").hide();
    }
  });
  
   
 $('.filter-dropdown').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('filter-open');
  }); 
  $('.filter-dropdown .w-dyn-item').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents().find('filter-open').removeClass('filter-open');
  });

  var seen = {};
  $('.filter-dropdown .w-dyn-item>div').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (seen[txt])
      $(this).remove();
    else
      seen[txt] = true;
  });

  $('.filter-dropdown').on('click', '.w-dyn-item', function() {
    $(".dropdown-btns-mobile>div").text($(this).text().replace('.', ' '));

  });
  $grid.isotope('layout');
    return false;
    }, 3000);
  });
  
 

 </script>
```