# Wrapping $(document).ready inside $(window).load?

Tags: jquery, ajax, document, document-ready, window-load

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622906/isotope-overlapping-images), I need to wrap all of my code in `$(window).load(function(){`. However, my gallery is also using imagesLoaded (to load images when they are ready) and ajax to load more items on a button click. My current layout is like this:

```
function initialise(){
//code goes here, including imagesLoaded
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    initialise();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    initialise();

//ajax code goes here
});
```

How can I wrap all of this in `$(window).load(function () {`?

Comment: `$(function(){ ...<your code here>... });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this!

```
$(window).load(function () {
    function initialise(){
    //code goes here, including imagesLoaded
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        initialise();
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        initialise();

    //ajax code goes here
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok wow. I tried that because that makes the most sense and it wasn't working. I'm sure there was just a typo or something. Totally working now. Thank you!